# Apache Tika - read chunk at a time from a file?

Tags: apache, apache-tika

Is there any way to read chunk at a time (instead of reading the entire file) from a file using Tika API?

following is my code. As you can see I am reading the entire file at once. I would like to read chunk at a time and create a text file the content.

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata meta =new Metadata();
WriteOutContentHandler handler = new WriteOutContnetHandler(-1);
ParseContext parse = new ParseContext();

....
p.parse(stream,handler,meta, context);
...

String content = handler.toString();
```

Comment: Apache Tika provides a stream of SAX events for the file's contents, can you not just read a handful of those then pause until you're ready for the next chunk?

Comment: I am not clear about what you mean. Would you please give a small example?

Comment: You'd need a custom SAX ContentHandler, rather than a built in one like BodyContentHandler. Grab the bits you care about from that, then when you have enough, don't return to Tika from the SAX handler until you've done your processing of the chunk. (I can't give code examples without knowing how you're calling Tika, nor why you want to chunk...)

Comment: Thanks. My question is updated with my code. The files are too large. I need to create a text file with just the file text contents.

Comment: OK, final question - how do you define a "chunk"?

Comment: Let's say that if the file is 10GB, I would like to read 100MB (a chuck) at at time and append to a text file.

Comment: 100mb of input, or 100mb of output? (One is easier than the other!). And are you only interested in plain text, or do you want html?

Comment: The file contains 10GB text. and I want to read and write 100MB plain text at a time.

Comment: If you're trying to process a 10gb text file, what does using Apache Tika give you? (It certainly makes sense if you have a wide range of file types, but if all you have is giant text files you'd be better off doing something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's (now) and Apache Tika example which shows how you can capture the plain text output, and return it in chunks based on the maximum allowed size of a chunk. You can find it in [ContentHandlerExample - method is parseToPlainTextChunks](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ContentHandlerExample.java)

Based on that, if you wanted to output to a file instead, and on a per-chunk basis, you'd tweak it to be something like:

```
final int MAXIMUM_TEXT_CHUNK_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
final File outputDir = new File("/tmp/");

private class ChunkHandler extends ContentHandlerDecorator {
   private int size = 0;
   private int fileNumber = -1;
   private OutputStreamWriter out = null;

   @Override
   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws IOException {
      if (out == null || size+length > MAXIMUM_TEXT_CHUNK_SIZE) {
         if (out != null) out.close();
         fileNumber++;
         File f = new File(outputDir, "output-" + fileNumber + ".txt);
         out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f, "UTF-8"));
      }
      out.write(ch, start, length);
   }
   public void close() throws IOException {
      if (out != null) out.close();
   }
}

public void parse(File file) {
   InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
   Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();
   Metadata meta =new Metadata();
   ContentHandler handler = new ChunkHandler();
   ParseContext parse = new ParseContext();

   p.parse(stream,handler,meta, context);
   ((ChunkHandler)handler).close();
}
```

That will give you plain text files in the given directory, of no more than a maximum size. All html tags will be ignored, you'll only get the plain textual content

Comment: You can do whatever you want! This is an example of a simple way to split based on plain text size only. If you want to restrict by tags, just override `startElement` or `endElement` and do your length checking there

Comment: Thanks for the example. When I try to read a pdf using this, I get error:   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1475)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:296)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:172)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1090)

 ... 4 more

Comment: Does that PDF parse without chunking? Only that exception looks at first glance to be like the kind of exception you'd get on a corrupted pdf file

Comment: It's happening with all pdf files.

Comment: I can drag and drop the files into tika-app-xx.jar and see no errors